# How to catch atrr transform translatex value?

Tags: javascript, css

I have div, which has some attributes style.

```
<div class="js__scroll__canvas" style="width: 10054px; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px); height: 521px;">
```

Another plugin js changes  transform: translate(**0px**, 0px) value (bold) - so x position.

I try to catch this value change.

```
var currentPos = parseInt($(".scroll-container .js__scroll__canvas").attr('style','transform').split(',')[4]);
$(document).on('change', currentPos , function() {
    alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

But nothing. I try to output `currentPos` value, but nothing returns, not null, or array, or anything else.

I see unusual structure of style attr transform - `transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);`. May be problem in that?

Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `.css` not `.attr`:

```
var currentPos = parseInt($(".scroll-container .js__scroll__canvas").css('transform').split(',')[4])
```

The code you have would set the style attribute to `"transform"`:

```
.attr('style','transform')
```

Also, this won't work:

```
$(document).on('change', currentPos , function() {
```

The second argument to `on` should be a JQuery selector, not a number. Try this:

```
var element = $(".scroll-container .js__scroll__canvas");
var currentPos = parseInt(element.css('transform').split(',')[4]);
element.on('change', function() {
    var newPos = parseInt(element.css('transform').split(',')[4]);

    if(currentPos != newPos) {
       currentPos = newPos;
       alert("It changed!");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have created div, try to set width(currentPos) - no style added.

Comment: Not shows allert...i understand your logic, but code doesn't work